# Can i integrate firebase chat to my application that has uses mysql database for the user login?

Tags: android, mysql, firebase

I'm considering integrating firebase chat in my application that uses a MySQL database for the sign up and login. Will this be possible or do I need to use Firebase for the entire back end.

Comment: This is possible, don't worry.
Ping me up if you required any help!

Comment: Thanks man i will message you soon